# store-and-forward or cut-through switching default for cisco switches?

Tags: cisco-ios, switching

Finding conflicting information online.  Looks like Cisco Nexus switches are cut-through by default and can be changed.  Also looks like IOS switches are store-and-forward by default and some can be changed and some can't (like a 3750 switch).

Can someone shed some light on this please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any IOS switches that can be set to cut-through.  My impression was that they were all store-and-forward.  As an example, a quick google search reveals cisco pages that state fixed store-and-forward behavior for [3750-X and 3560-X](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_58_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/swadmin.html), [2960 and 2960-S](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_53_se/configuration/guide/2960scg/swadmin.html), etc.  I think the reasons for this are two-fold.  First, ASICs have sped up switches so much that any gains from cut-through are small.  And second, Cisco switches are purchased at least in part due to their wide range of features - many of which probably require reading the whole frame.  Certainly, QoS requires store-and-forward, as well as, I would expect, layer 3 security features.

I also saw the documentation that you probably did regarding the Nexus switches.  Their intended use is very different than the typical IOS based switch.  They are used in server farms that require high bandwidth, low latency connections among the servers, storage area networks, and other data center elements.  So it is expected that the very low latency gains do help in some of these scenarios, while advanced security and QoS type features are occurring at the edge of the data center rather than in the middle of it where cut-through is useful.

Comment: That sounds about right.  The documentation I was reading before that included configuration on cut-through was for the Nexus series.

Comment: It is worth noting (and the purpose of why I posted this question) that the CCENT/CCNA exams ask to know cut-through/store-and-forward/fragment-free switching <- not sure why they would ask this information if only the Nexus family utilized these features...

Comment: Yeah, I remember they cover those 3 variations.  I think the main reasons are historical.  Back in the day the latency introduced by store-and-forward was significant for many networking scenarios.  Plus, knowing about the forwarding methods helps reinforce one's knowledge of frames and concepts like the data plane.

Comment: I agree nw0.  I read some more documentation on this from Cisco.  I think it is now safe to state that (at least for the purposes of the CCNA exam) most IOS switches are store-and-forward and cannot be changed.

Thanks everyone for the discussion.